# how is google mock implemented

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I would like to understand how some of the constructs in google mock are implemented. Specifically, I would like to understand how the `EXPECT_CALL` within an `In sequence` block below (taken from their documentation) is able to validate the ordering of arguments and sequence with which the calls are made. Yes, reverse engineering the macros can help but a big picture simplified overview of the internals with an example of the techniques used would help the community overall.

```
TEST(FooTest, DrawsLineSegment) {
  ...
  {
    InSequence seq;

    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown());
    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, Forward(100));
    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenUp());
  }
  Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's done exactly, but I imagine you can initialize some global state in `Insequence`'s constructor and record order of `EXPECT_CALL()`s in it. Then, when checking for calls verify only next corresponding record, instead of all records as usual.

Comment: Yes, but how does one handle multiple ```Insequence``` blocks or nested blocks for example? Perhaps a combination of file and name mangling of object name along with a global stack like structure to handle the nesting..